# Delete a row from a table by id

Tags: javascript, html, dom, row

I have a little problem. I have some dynamically created tables and each row has an id. I want to delete the row with the id "x".

I tried the usual method (removeChild) but it doesn't work for tables apparently.

```
function deleteRow(tableid, rowid)  
{   
      document.getElementById(tableid).removeChild(document.getElementById(rowid));  
}
```

The error I get is: Node was not found" code: "8

I also tried this:

```
function deleteRow(tbodyid, rowid)   
{  
      document.getElementById(tbodyid).removeChild(document.getElementById(rowid));   
}
```

and got the same error.

I can't use the `deleteRow()` method because that one needs the index of the row and I prefer not to search for the id mark the index then delete (even though if I don't find other solutions...).

Comment: You could get the row index by `rowElement.rowIndex`...

Comment: Could you add an example table to test with, It could be something strange in the way the table is designed.

Comment: For other people having the same problem:  This is happening for the first code snippet because the parent of a <TR> in a table is *always* a <THEAD>, <TBODY>, or <TFOOT> element.  If you don't wrap your <TR> inside one of these in your HTML, the DOM will automatically insert a <TBODY>, and this will be the parent of your <TR>, *not the <TABLE> element*.  So `removeChild()` called from the table element will fail.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

How about:

```
function deleteRow(rowid)  
{   
    var row = document.getElementById(rowid);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
}
```

And, if that fails, this should really work:

```
function deleteRow(rowid)  
{   
    var row = document.getElementById(rowid);
    var table = row.parentNode;
    while ( table && table.tagName != 'TABLE' )
        table = table.parentNode;
    if ( !table )
        return;
    table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Your first choice worked great for me.  I had fooled around with rowIndex without success, but it's good to see this example.

Comment: Excellent job ( second method )

Comment: In IE7, the `removeChild(row)` method worked better for me. The table column widths remain flexible, whereas using `table.deleteRow` they get stuck.

Comment: @Agostino  - It's 2021. If you still need to support IE7, good luck to you, but you're on your own. Those ancient browsers were weird...

Answer (score 2):

And what about trying not to delete but hide that row?

Comment: well... except the fact that there are about 80000 and it would work pretty bad... I check for it's existence then get data from it if it exists (I could check for display:none  also but I think is faster to check undefined).

Answer (score 2):

From this [post](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2008/05/20/javascript-remove-row-from-table/), try this javascript:

```
function removeRow(id) {
  var tr = document.getElementById(id);
  if (tr) {
    if (tr.nodeName == 'TR') {
      var tbl = tr; // Look up the hierarchy for TABLE
      while (tbl != document && tbl.nodeName != 'TABLE') {
        tbl = tbl.parentNode;
      }

      if (tbl && tbl.nodeName == 'TABLE') {
        while (tr.hasChildNodes()) {
          tr.removeChild( tr.lastChild );
        }
      tr.parentNode.removeChild( tr );
      }
    } else {
      alert( 'Specified document element is not a TR. id=' + id );
    }
  } else {
    alert( 'Specified document element is not found. id=' + id );
  }
}
```

I tried this javascript in a test page and it worked for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

to Vilx-:

```
var table = row.parentNode;
while ( table && table.tagName != 'TABLE' )
    table = table.parentNode;
```

and what if `row.parentNode` is `TBODY`?

You should check it out first, and after that
do `while` by `.tBodies`, probably

Answer (score 1):

Something quick and dirty:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function del_tr(remtr)  
{   
    while((remtr.nodeName.toLowerCase())!='tr')
        remtr = remtr.parentNode;

    remtr.parentNode.removeChild(remtr);
}
function del_id(id)  
{   
        del_tr(document.getElementById(id));
}
</script>
```

if you place

```
<a href='' onclick='del_tr(this);return false;'>x</a>
```

anywhere within the row you want to delete, than its even working without any ids

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the row is not the object you think, this is what I understand from the error.
Try detecting the parent of the row first, then you can be sure what to write into `getElementById` part of the parent.

Answer (score -1):

```
*<tr><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove">X</a></tr>*
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $("table").on('click', '.remove', function () {
       $(this).parent().parent('tr').remove();
  });
```