# Adding a delete button in PHP on each row of a MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add a delete button on each row so that I can delete a record when the button is pressed. I am new to PHP and MySQL and Stack Overflow.

Below is my table which extract information from my MySQL database and that works.

```
       <table class="table" >
       <tr>
       <th> Staff ID </th>
       <th> Staff Name </th>
       <th> Class </th>
       <th> Action </th>

       </tr>   

       <?php

       while($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Staff_ID']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Staff_Name']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Class']."</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       }// end while loop
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281598/how-to-delete-a-specific-row-in-a-table-using-javascript#comment73631786_43281598

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply using PHP as follows (You can use JS)

```
while($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$book['Staff_ID']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$book['Staff_Name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$book['Class']."</td>";
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$book['Staff_ID']."'></a></td>"; //if you want to delete based on staff_id
echo "</tr>";
}// end while loop
```

In your `delete.php` file,

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
//Connect DB
//Create query based on the ID passed from you table
//query : delete where Staff_id = $id
// on success delete : redirect the page to original page using header() method
$dbname = "your_dbname";
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usernname", "password", $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// sql to delete a record
$sql = "DELETE FROM Bookings WHERE Staff_ID = $id"; 

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header('Location: book.php'); //If book.php is your main page where you list your all records
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked :) Wish mu university tutors respond like this! cheers:)

Comment: <?php

//Connection and input to the database and server 

$db = mysqli_connect("server", "usernname", "password");

if(!$db)
{
echo "not connected to server";
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($db,"username"))
{
echo "database not selected";
}

require 'book.php'; //this is the file where  we created the button 

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql_delete = "DELETE FROM Bookings WHERE Staff_ID = $id";

header ("location: book.php");

?> 
@webDev  am I doing something wrong here? sorry about this

Comment: see updated code and you dont need to require book.php @HamzahAmir

Comment: THANK YOU AGIAN SOLVED IT!:)

Comment: This is simple but powerful!!

Comment: is it safe? what if someone put "delete.php?id=xx" in url? isn't it going to be  sql injection friendly?

Comment: yes you are right @judy but as poster seems like in beginner stage thats next step is to explore about prepared statements and input filtering (escaping) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Create a delete.php file that receives a $_GET['id'], then runs sql to delete that record when they go to that page. Done via two ways: an anchor tag like I've shown below,

Or make a button instead of an anchor runs ajax (through jquery) sending that id and running the the delete.php script from above I mentioned.

```
table class="table" >
       <tr>
       <th> Staff ID </th>
       <th> Staff Name </th>
       <th> Class </th>
       <th> Action </th>

       </tr>   

       <?php

       while($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Staff_ID']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Staff_Name']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$book['Class']."</td>";
       echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$book['Staff_ID']."'>Delete</a></td>";
       echo "</tr>";
       }// end while loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Ajax to make a call, something like @webDev but instead of calling the PHP, call a Javascript with an AjaxCall, and then, use JS to hide/delete the row in question, that way, the user didn't have to reload the whole page.

You can complement the answer you select as correct with this code instead of the href:

```
echo   '<td><button onclick="deleteRow('.$book['Staff_ID'].')">Delete</button></td>';
```

And add the following function in the `<head>` section:

```
<script>
    function deleteRow(StaffID){
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {                     

        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                  alert("Deleted!");
            }
        };
        document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(x);
        xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("id="+StaffID);
        }       
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I know, but the user who posted the question is beginner, and for beginner its better to have simple answer as much as we can. While learning its better to understand using PHP first