# Bind function to button onclick in a loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table nested within a form that looks as follows:

[image]

The "leave_request_processor.php" file that receives the post request from the above file then reads as follows:

```
$approved = "Approved";

$rejected = "Rejected";

foreach($all_leave_ids as $leave_id){

    if(isset($_POST["approve"])){

    $strQuery2 = "UPDATE leave_applications SET status = '$approved' WHERE application_id = '$leave_id' ";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection,$strQuery2) or Exit ("Query execution failed");

    mysqli_close($connection);

    header("Location: leave_check.php"); /* Redirect browser */

    exit();

        }

    else if (isset($_POST["reject"])){

    $strQuery3 = "UPDATE leave_applications SET status = '$rejected' WHERE application_id = '$leave_id' ";

    $result3 = mysqli_query($connection,$strQuery3) or Exit ("Query execution failed");

    mysqli_close($connection);

    header("Location: leave_check.php"); /* Redirect browser */

    exit();

    }

   }
```

The code works but starting with the first row (whichever rows' button you click) in descending order then the page reloads and you're left with the pending requests.

I bet there's a way you can code it (I'm thinking JavaScript) so that if I click "Approve" on row 23 it acts on that row. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can just use one form per row instead of one form for all rows. That's probably the most straight-forward.

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt. I found a makeshift workaround here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286487/5925104)

Answer (score 0):

@Rasclatt I tried this out. Is this what you had in mind? Didn't work though.

```
$strQuery = "SELECT * from leave_applications WHERE status = 'Pending' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $strQuery) or Exit("Query execution failed");

if($result->num_rows>0){


    // output data of each row

echo "<table class='pure-table pure-table-bordered'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Application ID</th>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Days Requested</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th colspan='2'>ACTION TO TAKE</th>
    </tr>
</thead>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    array_push($allleaveids,$row["application_id"]);

    echo 
"<form action='leave_request_processor.php' method='post' target='_self' name='leave_check' class='pure-form pure-form-aligned'>
    <tr>
    <td>".$row["application_id"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["student_id"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["email"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["days_requested"]."</td>
    <td>".$row["status"]."</td>
    <td><button class='button-success pure-button' name='approve' type='submit'>Approve</button></td>
    <td><button class='button-error pure-button' name='reject' type='submit'>Reject</button></td>
    </tr>
    </form>";   
echo "</table>";
}   

}
```